# Android PreferenceFragment : Setting status bar as per tool bar color

Tags: android, toolbar, android-actionbaractivity, preferencefragment

How to set status bar color as per toolbar color of PreferenceFragment?
I want green color in my status bar. My application is also supporting pre-lollipop devices.
Thanks in advance

Screenshot of my problem:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/013x4Mo.png]

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.timepass.sampleapp.Settings"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/action_settings" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PreferencesActivity.java

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsPreference())
            .commit();
}

public static class SettingsPreference extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // applyTheme();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to change the color of the status bar only in this fragment, or in the role application?

Comment: @Renan Lopes Ferreira, only in this fragment.

Comment: No one with solution >

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(yourColor);
```

and for pre-Lollipop devices use this [library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint)